# MassTransit: How can we configure Multiple bus (Both Rabbit mq)

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a requirement where I need to read message from one rabbit mq and publish it to another.
I tried configuring both the host, but when i publish it publishes only to the first configured rabbit mq.

I got the multibus running but now I am stuck with healthcheck

Both of the bus are returning status under IBus

{
"status": "Unhealthy",
"results": {
"IBus": {
"status": "Healthy",
"description": "Ready",
"data": {
"Endpoints": {
"rabbitmq://localhost:5672/XXXXX_Sxxxxxxx_bus_39pyyy81rrcpzwhibdcedd8sno?temporary=true": {
"Message": "ready (not started)"
},
"rabbitmq://localhost:5673/XXXXX_Sxxxxxxx_bus_39pyyy81rrcpzwhibdcedd8sno?temporary=true": {
"Message": "ready (not started)"
},
"rabbitmq://localhost:5673/xxxxxConsumer": {
"Message": "ready"
},
"rabbitmq://localhost:5672/xxxxxx--xxxxxConsumer": {
"Message": "ready"
}
}
}
},
"IRabbitMqBusB": {
"status": "Unhealthy",
"description": "Not ready: not started",
"data": {
"Endpoints": {}
}
}
}
}

Answer (score 1):

It's called MultiBus and thoroughly described in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/multibus.html#multibus).

In addition, it doesn't "publish to the first configured bus". It only does that if you use a DI container and use the resolved `IPublishEndpointProvider`. Since it's registered as a singleton with `Try`, you won't get the second instance registered.

If you don't use the DI container and use the bus instance, you can do whatever you want. The MultiBus feature allows you to use multiple bus instances registered in the container.

Comment: Thank you for response.. I got it working.. but I got stuck with the health check..

Comment: can you help me out with this